# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out with AWs

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, magento2, rds

[image]

unable to process the next step due to Time-out issue.
we have created the instance in RDS-AWS, linkup with the MYSQL Workbeanch .

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a security group or networking issue.

- Check if the required ports are open.
- Check if your hosted Magento EC2 instance is in the same VPC as that
  of the RDS instance.

Comment: thank you for the support. we have rebulit the RDS instance, we found the error to configure the instance in Multi A-Z we suppose to keep Yes insteed of No. which was the cause of the error.